# HttpResponseRedirect в Django. Can't do redirect on 'done' page

Tags: python, django, django-views

After filling the page should appear 'done', but i have an error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidate/done.html
The current path, candidate/done.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Can't configure redirect to 'done' page.

Here **views.py**:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import AnketaForm
from .models import Anketa

def anketa_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnketaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('candidate/done.html')
    else:
        form = AnketaForm()
    return render(request, 'candidate/anketa_create.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py** (apps/candidate)

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.anketa_create_view, name = 'anketa_create_view'),
    ]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from candidate.views import anketa_create_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('done/', anketa_create_view),
    path('', anketa_create_view),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: The name of the template, `candidate/done.html` is different from the URL `done/`. The smallest change to fix the error would be to do `HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')`. But an even better solution is to avoid hardcoding the URL, like in bmons answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove in **urls.py**

> `path('done/', anketa_create_view)`

and replace in **views.py**

> `return HttpResponseRedirect('candidate/done.html')`

to

> `return render(request, 'candidate/done.html', {})`

Answer (score 1):

you need to give a name to the done url

```
path('done/', anketa_create_view, name='done'),
```

and can do with reverse

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('done'))
```

or you can do redirect shortcut

```
return redirect('done')
```

Comment: it works, but return empty form. I think I should make changes in anketa_create.html?